# Issue with Group by Mysql query

Tags: mysql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have been stumped by this MySQL query for the past few day,and seeking some expert help before i throw my PC out of the window, lol.

I have a table that consists of invoices; invoice number column name is Trans_ref$$ (primary key).

each invoice is linked to a job , column name is OPSREF$$_ORIGINAL (foreign key).

Both columns are in the same table.

a job can have multiple invoices.

Now the issue is i'm trying to create a query that will identify the FIRST invoice in sequence (Trans_ref$$) in a job group and if that FIRST invoice is with a date range then output the job (OPSREF$$_ORIGINAL). 
The invoice number is sequential and a unique number.

I have tried using a case / min group by statement to identify the first invoice in a job group within a data range, however this query is not isolating the first invoice within a date range, instead it is just outputting 1st or 2nd or 3rd positioned invoice in job group that matches the date range….I hope this makes sense .

I have included a screen shot of the table and the desired output, and would appreciate if someone 
Hello
I have been stumped by this query for the past day,and seeking some expert help before i throw my PC out of the window, lol.

I have a table that consists of invoices; invoice number column name is Trans_ref$$ (primary key).

each invoice is linked to a job , column name is OPSREF$$_ORIGINAL (foreign key).

Both columns are in the same table.

a job can have multiple invoice.

Now the issue is i'm trying to create a query that will identify the FIRST invoice (Trans_ref$$) in a job group and if that FIRST invoice is with a date range then output the job (OPSREF$$_ORIGINAL). 
The invoice number in a sequential / unique number.

I have tried using a case / min group by statement to identify the first invoice in a job group within a data range, however this query is not isolating the first invoice within a date range, instead it is just outputting 1st or 2nd or 3rd positioned invoice in job group that matches the date range….I hope this makes sense .

Here the code I have used

```
SET @START_DATE := "2014-08-27";
SET @END_DATE:= "2014-09-02";

select 
count(TRANS_REF$$),
Case 
when min(TRANS_REF$$) and INVOICE_DATE_D8>=@START_DATE and INVOICE_DATE_D8<=@END_DATE
then OPSREF$$_ORIGINAL
end as OPSREF$$_ORIGINAL
from INVOICE_HEADER_UNS
where 
TRANSACTION_STATUS = 9
and Tmode$$="06"
group by OPSREF$$_ORIGINAL
```

So to breakdown the process in stages.....

**1. grab each OPSREF$$_ORIGINAL group within the INVOICE_HEADER_UNS table**

```
Date Range - Start 27/08/2014 - End 02/09/2014                  

TABLE - INVOICE_HEADER_UNS                  

TRANS_REF$$ INVOICE_DATE_D8    OPSREF$$_ORIGINAL                
---------------------------------------------
|   1       |    26/08/2014 |  ABC          | 
|   2       |    02/08/2014 |  ABC          |  
---------------------------------------------
|   3       |    28/08/2014 |  DDD          |  
|   4       |    09/09/2014 |  DDD          |  
---------------------------------------------
|   5       |   01/01/2013  |  JJJ          |
|   6       |   21/12/2013  |  JJJ          |
---------------------------------------------
|   7       |   01/09/2014  |  LLL          |
---------------------------------------------
```

**2. within each OPSREF$$_ORIGINAL group, look at TRANS_REF$$ sequence and find the first TRANS_REF$$ in that OPSREF$$_ORIGINAL group.**

```
Date Range - Start 27/08/2014 - End 02/09/2014                  

TABLE - INVOICE_HEADER_UNS                  

TRANS_REF$$ INVOICE_DATE_D8    OPSREF$$_ORIGINAL           Is First inv?                
--------------------------------------------------------
|   1       |    26/08/2014 |  ABC                      |  yes           
|   2       |    02/08/2014 |  ABC                      |  no           
--------------------------------------------------------
|   3       |    28/08/2014 |  DDD                      |  yes           
|   4       |    09/09/2014 |  DDD                      |  no            
---------------------------------------------------------
|   5       |   01/01/2013  |  JJJ                      |  yes               
|   6       |   21/12/2013  |  JJJ                      |  no            
---------------------------------------------------------
|   7       |   01/09/2014  |  LLL                      |  yes               
---------------------------------------------------------
```

**3. Look at the the FIRST INVOICE in the ordered sequence for the group and check the INVOICE_DATE_D8 for that row and see if it is within date range ( 27/08/2014 - 02/09/2014    )**

```
Date Range - Start 27/08/2014 - End 02/09/2014                  

TABLE - INVOICE_HEADER_UNS                  

TRANS_REF$$ INVOICE_DATE_D8    OPSREF$$_ORIGINAL            Is First inv?    In date range?         
--------------------------------------------------------
|   1       |    26/08/2014 |  ABC                      |  yes              no

--------------------------------------------------------
|   3       |    28/08/2014 |  DDD                      |  yes              yes

---------------------------------------------------------
|   5       |   01/01/2013  |  JJJ                      |  yes              no

---------------------------------------------------------
|   7       |   01/09/2014  |  LLL                      |  yes              yes
```

**4. Does each row meet the criteria (i.e. first invoice and in date - YES + YES) ? if correct then output the distinct OPSREF$$_ORIGINAL for that row**

Here is the desired output from the example above

```
Date Range - Start 27/08/2014 - End 02/09/2014                  

TABLE - INVOICE_HEADER_UNS                  

OPSREF$$_ORIGINAL         Is First inv?    In date range?           
------------------------
|  DDD                  |  yes                yes
------------------------
|  LLL                  |  yes                yes
------------------------
```

Based on this, can you suggest how I can do this? thanks

Here is the Table definition;

tablename - INVOICE_HEADER_UNS

```
**TRANS_REF$$**    char(7) - Primary key

INVOICE_DATE_D8    datatime                 

OPSREF$$_ORIGINAL    char(11)
```

---

16/09/2014 - Here is the query that appears to be returning the correct results using DRapp syntax, however the query needs to be optimised somehow as when I bolt this onto the bigger query as a sub query it causes my MYSQL workbench to crash. After doing an explain on the query , it appears to be indexing through 28,309 rows. How can i optimise this query without impacting the results?

I have tried adding the below to the where clause however it adds more records to the overall query output, but indexes 979 rows instead/

```
set @START_DATE := '2014-08-27';
set @END_DATE := '2014-09-02';

SELECT

if (min(ihu.INVOICE_DATE_D8)>= @START_DATE and min(ihu.INVOICE_DATE_D8)<= @END_DATE     ihu.opsref$$_original, null) as firstinvoiceindaterange

from
INVOICE_HEADER_UNS ihu

join CONSIGNMENT_ALL_HEADER_UNS on ihu.OUR_REF = CONSIGNMENT_ALL_HEADER_UNS.OPSREF$$

where ihu.TRANSACTION_STATUS = 9 and ihu.Tmode$$="06"

AND CONSIGNMENT_ALL_HEADER_UNS.CONS_TYPE$$ <>'7'

AND CONSIGNMENT_ALL_HEADER_UNS.CONS_TYPE$$ in ('3' , '5', '9')

#and ihu.INVOICE_DATE_D8>= @START_DATE and ihu.INVOICE_DATE_D8<= @END_DATE

group by

ihu.opsref$$_original
```

Comment: If I had to work with this naming policy I WOULD throw my PC out of the window. Also, note that this is MySQL, so these are not dates.

Comment: Please add table definitions

Comment: i have added table definitions

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help you out, and you can tweak it as needed.

```
SELECT
      ihu.opsref$$_original,
      MIN( ihu.TRANS_REF$$ ) MinRefForEntireJob,
      MIN( ihu.INVOICE_DATE_D8 ) MinDateForEntireJob,
      MIN( IF(    ihu.INVOICE_DATE_D8 >= @START_DATE
              AND ihu.INVOICE_DATE_D8 <= @END_DATE, ihu.TRANS_REF$$, null )) as MinRefWithinDateRange,
      MIN( IF(    ihu.INVOICE_DATE_D8 >= @START_DATE
              AND ihu.INVOICE_DATE_D8 <= @END_DATE, ihu.INVOICE_DATE_D8, null )) as MinDateWithinDateRange
   from
      INVOICE_HEADER_UNS ihu,
      ( select @START_DATE := '2014-08-27',
               @END_DATE := '2014-09-02' ) sqlvars
   group by
      ihu.opsref$$_original
```

Once you see these results, then you SHOULD be able to just add a HAVING clause something like

```
   HAVING
      MinDateWithinDateRange IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Hello DRapp. I have used your parts of your code, and think I have got the results i'm looking for, however when I BOLT this sub query onto the bigger query, it causes my system to crash. I used EXPLAIN to determine the problem and it could be that the ihu table alias is indexing through 28,309 rows!

Comment: @JohnSmith, it may be due to my version self-declaring the start/end dates in the FROM clause.  If you still have your start/end defined outside it, remove them from my "FROM" clause. As for the going through 28k+ rows, you had no WHERE clause.  You may need to add that so it is not querying the entire database, not just the fact that the dates are compared to the start/end of the invoice_date_d8 if invoices span outside the range.

Comment: Hi, I have added my revised version of the query to the original post above.., Can you advise how i can optimise it to prevent the system running through 28K records and not impacting the query output...if i add the where statement 'code' and ihu.INVOICE_DATE_D8>= "@START_DATE" and ihu.INVOICE_DATE_D8<= "@END_DATE" it adds more records to the query output than without. hope this makes sense.

Comment: @JohnSmith, I think the issue is you have probably years of data and querying for all of it, even though considered a limited range.  Let me ask this.  Are you ONLY CONCERNED with any invoices that have the INVOICE_DATE_D8 within the start/end date range?  Otherwise, maybe shrink the result by forcing the outer where clause to something like 2014-07-01 to current date, so you are only going back 2-3 months vs EVERYTHING in the database.